# JS: Ajax issue with json?

Tags: javascript

I have an API that returns the following JSON content.

```
{"server_online":"0"}
```

I'm trying to update a div's content to say "Online" or "Offline" depending on the 0 or 1 value.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.dev.net/get/server/status",
    success: function(result) {
        $('#server-status').html(result);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
    }       
});
```

My issue is, the content of the div updates to an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the property of the object:

```
$('#server-status').html(result.server_online ? "Online" : "Offline");
```

You should also use `dataType: "json"` in the `$.ajax` options to ensure that it gets parsed as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

In the ajax `success` you need to use `result` object and then add `if statement`. In the `if statement` you need to use jquery `append()` function which will add offline or onilne text to `div#server-status`

```
success: function(result) {
    if(result.server_online == 0){
            $('#server-status').append("<span>Offline</span>");
        }

    if(result.server_online == 1){
            $('#server-status').append("<span>online</span>");
     }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not accessing the object property `server_online`.

Simply do the following:

```
$('#server-status').html(result.server_online ? "Online" : "Offline");
```